# Python List Comprehension with multiple statements

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a for loop like this:

```
cols = ['Type','Gender','MaritalStatus']
    for i in cols:
        print(data[i].value_counts(normalize=True)*100)
        print('-'*35)
```

How do I write the same code using list comprehension? I was able to do this:

```
cols = [data[i].value_counts(normalize=True) for i in ['Type','Gender','MaritalStatus']]
cols
```

But how to use the `print('-'*35)` in the code?

Comment: A list comprehension is for when all you're doing in a loop is making a list (which is not the case here). You shouldn't use a comprehension for side effects

Comment: That actually makes sense. I get your point. Thank you.